# PDO Not Allowing Insertion Of Data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a script locally and have encountered a bit of a problem, which has me boggled. I am trying to insert some data into a table, and I'm just not getting it to insert. I have dumped all variables leading up to the execution of the actual query and they're all true and existing but once I dump the execution it is returning false. I am seriously stumped here. Can anyone assist me?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = '';
        $clan_name = $_POST['clan_name'];
        $short_desc = $_POST['clan_short_desc'];

        $database = Database::getDatabase();
        $driver = $database->getDriver();
        $stmt = $driver->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'clans
             VALUES (0, :id_user, :clan_name, :clan_short_desc, :clan_date, 0);'
        );
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_user', $user->getId(), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':clan_name', $clan_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':clan_short_desc', $short_desc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':clan_date', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        var_dump($stmt->bindValue(':id_user', $user->getId(), PDO::PARAM_STR));
        var_dump($stmt->bindValue(':clan_name', $clan_name, PDO::PARAM_STR));
        var_dump($stmt->bindValue(':clan_short_desc', $short_desc, PDO::PARAM_STR));
        var_dump($stmt->bindValue(':clan_date', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT));
        //header('Location: index.php?action=viewclans');
        //die();
    }
```

Comment: you are trying to insert user in users table? where the primary key is `id_user`?

Comment: so now you are trying to insert record into clans table? where first field (I don't know the column name) id? and you are setting that key to 0 again and again? `VALUES (0, `

Comment: @Alex The primary key will be ID which is AI. id_user is just the users ID who added the data. Didn't realize I had the wrong table name, thought that might be the problem but alas the script still doesn't insert any data.

Comment: What errors? Database Schema?

Comment: @davidstrachan There are no errors being thrown. Here's a picture of the table: http://i.gyazo.com/22c9218e295eb1854e01997037d49d80.png

Comment: Pleased you got this fixed. Two small tips when asking database-related questions: schemas should generally be supplied within the question in the first edit - it's the first thing people will ask for. Also, they are best supplied as text not images - a `CREATE TABLE` statement is excellent, but an ASCII table is fine too. Column names and types are the main thing people want to know, and relationships between multiple tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just :

```
'INSERT INTO ' . TABLE_PREFIX . 'clans 
  (id_user,clan_name, clan_short_description, clan_date)
VALUES 
  ( :id_user, :clan_name, :clan_short_desc, :clan_date);'
```

and add right after execute:

```
$stmt->execute(); 
print_r ($stmt->errorInfo());
```

Comment: No luck. :/ Could the actual SETTINGS of the database effect this at all? http://i.gyazo.com/0ef355b3bdd88ac3b3e2e8f0292bef6a.png

Comment: no. show me your `CREATE TABLE` statement for `clans` table

Comment: why table name is different? there is no AUTO_INCREMENT column

Comment: The table name is the same. clansoc_ is the prefix.

Comment: 'PDOStatement::errorInfo():
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\clansoc\models\CreateClan.php on line 50
Array'

Comment: Well... Lol... That brought a simple spelling error to light... Litterally facepalming right now because I've been at this for about 3 1/2 hours...